# How can I get customer_taxvat on sales flat quote in - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-quote

public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {

```
    $customerAttributes = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->loadAllAttributes()->getAttributesByCode();
    $attributes = array();


    foreach ($customerAttributes as $attribute) {
        $attribute[] = $customerAttributes;
        if (!($attribute->getFrontendLabel()) || !($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
            continue;
        }
        $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $attrLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
        if($attrCode == 'default_shipping' || $attrCode == 'default_billing') {
            continue;
        }
        $attributes[$attrCode] = $attrLabel;
    }
    asort($attributes);
    $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
    return $this;
}
```

this is my code, but I need to some validations, 1- If attributes is empty, i would like to get customer_taxvat in sales_flat_quote

You got it?

Answer (score 0):

> **Using Order Collection You Can Easily Get `customer_taxvat` value**

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

foreach ($order_collection as $data)
{
    $customer_taxvat = $data->getData('customer_taxvat');
}
```